# any in python doesn't print content

Tags: python, any

I am playing with `any`, and found this:

```py
def f():
    print(1)
    return True


def g():
    print(2)
    return False


if any(lambda x: x() for x in [g, f, f]):
    print(3)
```

I guess I would get

```py
2
3
```

or

```py
2
1
3
```

but only get

```py
3
```

I don't know why.

Comment: ``lambda x: x()`` defines a function which *would call ``x`` when called*. It does not actually call ``x``. Any of ``if any(x() for x in [g, f, f]):`` and ``if any((lambda x: x())() for x in [g, f, f]):`` will work.

Comment: You haven't passed an iterable containing the results of executing the three functions to `any`, you've passed a generator that will yield three lambdas. I assume that a lambda is truthy when evaluated (note: it is not called, just checked for truthiness) and thus `any` succeeds. Possibly you wanted something more like `any(x() for x in [g, f, f])`?

Comment: @Kemp Yes, a lambda expression produces an instance of `function`, which is considered truthy.

Comment: @Kemp It's actually a generator expression containing three lambdas

Comment: @wjandrea Correct, my reading was a little off

Comment: @MisterMiyagi This would make sense if Python was a compiled language. An interpreter still has to go over the `print(2)` to reach to `True` and then passes `any`

Comment: @anishtain4 This does not have anything to do with compilation. The functions are never called. The truth value comes from the function itself – ``bool(lambda x: x())`` is ``True``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi The posted answer makes it clear. I couldn't read that from your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lambda is never actually called, so it itself is evaluated, and function objects are apparently truthy.

```
>>> bool(lambda: False)
True
>>> bool(max)
True
>>> bool(f)
True
```

Simply remove the lambda part:

```
if any(x() for x in [g, f, f]):
    print(3)
```

Output:

```
2
1
3
```

Comment: And if you add `not ` before the `x()` you get your first guessed result.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is at line

```
if any(lambda x: x() for x in [g, f, f]):
```

**any** function will return **True** and it will print only **3**,like it supposed to because you are returning some lambda objects but you are not calling them.

So if you want to behave like you expected you should try this:

```
if any(x() for x in [g, f, f]):
```